# Cannot turn on Bitlocker on 1 SSD drive, can turn on on 2 other drives of the same laptop

Tags: windows-10, encryption, bitlocker, disk-encryption

I want to turn on Bitlocker on a Laptop. Windows 10 LTSC 2018, Core I7, 32 GB RAM, DELL 7540, 2 NVMA SSD + 1 2.5" 2TB SSD.

I can turn on Bitlocker on both NVME (one OS and one data drive) but not on the 2 TB SSD data drive.

Why can I not activate Bitlocker there, the specific drive is not listed in control panel Bitlocker Drive Encryption.

edit:
disk 2 being the problematic one:

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          476 GB      0 B        *
  Disk 1    Online          465 GB  1024 KB
  Disk 2    Online         1863 GB      0 B
```

```
DISKPART> select disk 1

Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Primary            465 GB  1024 KB
```

```
DISKPART> select disk 0

Disk 0 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Recovery           499 MB  1024 KB
  Partition 2    System             100 MB   500 MB
  Partition 3    Reserved            16 MB   600 MB
  Partition 4    Primary            475 GB   616 MB
  Partition 5    Recovery           809 MB   476 GB
```

```
DISKPART> select disk 2

Disk 2 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Primary           1863 GB  1024 KB
```

Comment: How exactly are you turning it on and what is the error message?

Comment: @harrymc Control Panel - Bitlocker Drive Encryption. Set Bitlocker to ON for the specific drive. C&D are listed these are NVME. drive E is not listed and I cannot turn on Bitlocker for this

Comment: What is the difference? Are the drives perhaps formatted differently?

Comment: @harrymc no, both NTFS

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of Disk Management showing all three SSDs.

Comment: @harrymc: https://i.imgur.com/atVGh9r.png

Comment: @harrymc using manage-bde -on from [1] I get error 0x80070057. What does this mean?


[1] https://www.cocosenor.com/articles/windows-10/optional-ways-to-turn-on-and-use-bitlocker-encryption-on-windows-10.html

Comment: Have you tried to reformat the disk?

Comment: No, as I still have quite a bit of data on there. Bitlocker activated fine on the other data drive, whilst me using it.

Comment: I think BitLocker requires an extra partition (or free space) that doesn’t show up in Disk Management. Instead, we’ll try using `diskpart`. Enter `select disk 1`, then `list partition`, then `select disk 2`, then again `list partition`. Copy the result as text (do not take a screenshot) and [add it to your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1699012/edit) (not in a comment) using code block formatting. Also put the Disk Management screenshot there.

Comment: @DanielB I added the information

Comment: Yeah that doesn’t really support my theory, sorry. Maybe try shrinking the partition by 200 MB.